# Issue while Validating the well formed XML against XSD

Tags: java, xml, xsd, xsd-validation

I am working on creating a XML validator which will validate XML against a particular schema. I am currently using OASIS schema to validate an Assertion against that schema.Below is the schema when it is passed to SchemaFactory and schema object is created then xenc:EncryptedData element is not resolved which is present in imported schema xenc-schema.xsd"

And when I create an instance of SchemaFactory and try to load the schema , it is unable to locate the schemas imported in the above schema :

```
XML is not valid because 
src-resolve: Cannot resolve the name 'xenc:EncryptedData' to a(n) 'element declaration' component.
```

How can I resolve imported schemas on SchemaFactory when creating schema object should be able to locate imported schemas? Below is the code I am writing:

```
...
    System.out.println("Executing the value");
    SchemaFactory sf = SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);

    Source schemaFile = new StreamSource(new File("D:\\saml-schema-assertion-            2.0.xsd"));
    Schema schema = sf.newSchema(schemaFile);
    Validator validator = schema.newValidator();
    validator.setErrorHandler(new SAMLErrorHandler());

    validator.validate(new StreamSource(new File("D:\\Saml.xml")));
    System.out.println("XML is valid");
} catch (IOException ex) {
} catch (SAXException e) {
    System.out.println("XML is not valid because ");
    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
}
```

I am seeking for the responses.

Comment: The part of Oasis schema i am using is shared at :http://docs.oasis-open.org/security/saml/v2.0/saml-schema-assertion-2.0.xsd

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the `xenc` namespace is not declared in your XML file, or at least the whole element `xenc:EncryptedData`. Post your XML file, please. I don't see `EncryptedData` element definition in your XSD file.

Comment: Hi please refer to the below section in xds :- <simpleContent>
- <extension base="string">
  <attributeGroup ref="saml:IDNameQualifiers" /> 
  <attribute name="Format" type="anyURI" use="optional" /> 
  <attribute name="SPProvidedID" type="string" use="optional" /> 
  </extension>
  </simpleContent>
  </complexType>
- <complexType name="EncryptedElementType">
- <sequence>
  <element ref="xenc:EncryptedData" /> 
  <element ref="xenc:EncryptedKey" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" /> 
  </sequence>
  </complexType>

Comment: @SushantSood the link you provided does not contain this information. can you provide the XML and the XSD?